# Not able to Open PDF file by using Adobe in Nougat

Tags: android, pdf, adobe, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

I have research a lot but still I am not getting proper solution to open downloaded pdf in Adobe reader.
By using below code pdf gets opened using google doc app but not by adobe.

**To download pdf from Url**

```
 URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getFileName());

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_DISMISS];
                    while (true) {
                        int bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer);
                        if (bufferLength <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    FileLog.e("PDF Save", e);
                }
```

**To view saved PDF**

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getFileName());
    try {
           if (file.exists()) {
               Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            if (Utilities.isAboveNougat()) {
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "myPackage.fileprovider", file);
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");         
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

         } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
             mContext.startActivity(intent);
         }

    } else {
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not able to find downloaded file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ae) {
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "No activity found to open this attachment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
public static boolean isAboveNougat() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Manifest.xml;**

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"     
       android:authorities="myPackage.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>
```

I also tried following way to open pdf;

```
Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from((Activity) mContext)
                                .setStream(contentUri)
                                .setType("application/pdf")
                                .getIntent()
                                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                .setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf")                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But still not able to solve issue. While opening pdf using adobe its showing toast message;

> File could not be access please check location or network connection.

Comment: can you post fileprovider meta data in manifest, provider.xml and Utilities.isAboveNougat() code

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @priyankakamthe just to test once can u save the pdf files in a specific folder say **pdfs** and put that folder name at <external-path path="pdfs/"  name="external_storage_root" /> and try?

Comment: @Raghavendra I have tried but not working :(

Comment: @priyankakamthe did u get any errors?

Comment: @Raghavendra there is not any error in Logcat. Its only showing Toast message which i mention in post

Comment: @priyankakamthe while testing u have changed the line new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getFileName()); line also right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153784/discussion-between-priyanka-kamthe-and-raghavendra).

Comment: can you try this one in provider
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny I already tried that. See in my post I have provided PathFile xml code

Comment: Your provider is external_storage_root not external_files so can you try that or you already tried it

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny Oh wait let me try then.

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny quite not sure though name doesn't matter but path right?

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny yes name doesn't matter. but I tried your suggestion & its not working.

Comment: @priyankakamthe are u testing in Nougat or preNougat?

Comment: @priyankakamthe did u enable storage permission for your app? Looks to be that is the issue? I have tested your code its working in nougat

Comment: @Raghavendra Nougat

Comment: Can u check the app  permissions manually.. whether storage permission enabled or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came to know where I made mistake. While downloading pdf from Url its gets store in bytes & adobe not able to read that byte formatted file. So while saving that downloaded file we need to give **.pdf** extension, which I didn't gave while storing it. Most of the document viewing apps able to read byte formatted file like google's docs app.

I made changes in getFileName function;

```
private String getFileName() {
        String tempFileName = urlString.substring(urlString.length() - 10);
        String[] arrFilenames = tempFileName.split("\\.");
        return Utilities.getString(arrFilenames[0]+".pdf");            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "myPackage.fileprovider", file);
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");         
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

for nougat this works for me

Comment: Note: "myPackage.fileprovider" this should be same as we mention in FileProvider File.